# Getting duplicated instances using rawSocketStream in Spark Streaming

Tags: java, json, apache-spark, linked-list, spark-streaming

I have set up a server in Python which is sending a JSON line per 2 seconds to my Spark Streaming context via  ReceiverInputDStream rawSocketStream, like so:

```
JavaStreamingContext ssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf, Durations.seconds(2));

JavaReceiverInputDStream<String> streamData = ssc.socketTextStream(args[0], Integer.parseInt(args[1]),
            StorageLevels.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER);
```

Notice that that the Batch.Duration of my context is also of 2 seconds.
I then map the resulting stream, and return a LinkedList, which I then print, like so:

```
JavaDStream<LinkedList<StreamValue>> getdatatoplace = streamData.map(new Function<String, LinkedList<StreamValue>>() {
                @Override
                public LinkedList<StreamValue> call(String s) throws Exception {
                    stream_Value.push(s)
                    return stream_Value;
}

getdatatoplace.print();
```

Here is the problem: when I check the LinkedList's content, I see that each of my JSON lines is saved in duplicate in my list, so for example:

```
stream_Value[0]=jsonline1
stream_Value[1]=jsonline1
stream_Value[2]=jsonline2
stream_Value[3]=jsonline2
...
```

I tried to increase and decrease the batch duration of the context, as well as the time interval in which I send my JSON lines. Nothing changes.

Anyone know what's wrong? Thank you so much.

Comment: Are you sure you're not sending the data twice? Perhaps add the code which sends the data as well.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov, I will gladly post that code, but I am sure that I am not receiving duplicate values from that for a very simple reason: if I do streamdata.print(), the values are not duplicate.

Comment: don't use side-effects in `map` functions. It will only get you in trouble. See my answer to your other question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37000348/why-do-multiple-print-methods-in-spark-streaming-affect-the-values-in-my-list