# Why do multiple print() methods in Spark Streaming affect the values in my list?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I'm trying to receive one JSON line per two seconds, store them in a List which has elements from a costum Class, created by me,  and print the resulting List after each execution of the context. So I'm doing something like this:

```
JavaStreamingContext ssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf, Durations.seconds(2));

    JavaReceiverInputDStream<String> streamData = ssc.socketTextStream(args[0], Integer.parseInt(args[1]),
            StorageLevels.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER);


    JavaDStream<LinkedList<StreamValue>> getdatatoplace = streamData.map(new Function<String, LinkedList<StreamValue>>() {
                @Override
                public LinkedList<StreamValue> call(String s) throws Exception {
                    //Access specific attributes in the JSON
                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, String>>() {
                    }.getType();
                    Map<String, String> retMap = gson.fromJson(s, type);
                    String a = retMap.get("exp");

                    String idValue = retMap.get("id");

                    //insert values into the stream_Value LinkedList
                    stream_Value.push(new StreamValue(idValue, a, UUID.randomUUID()));


                    return stream_Value;

                }
            });

getdatatoplace.print();
```

This works very well, and I get the following result:

```
//at the end of the first batch duration/cycle
 getdatatoplace[]={json1}

//at the end of the second batch duration/cycle
 getdatatoplace[]={json1,json2}

...
```

However, if I do multiple prints of `getdatatoplace`, let's say 3:

```
 getdatatoplace.print();
 getdatatoplace.print();
 getdatatoplace.print();
```

then I get this result:

```
 //at the end of the first print
 getdatatoplace[]={json1}

//at the end of the second print
 getdatatoplace[]={json1,json1}

 //at the end of the third print
 getdatatoplace[]={json1,json1,json1}

//Context ends with getdatatoplace.size()=3

//New cycle begins, and I get a new value json2

 //at the end of the first print
 getdatatoplace[]={json1,json1,json1,json2}
...
```

So what happens is that, for each print that I do, even though I do `stream_Value.push` before, and the commands I gave in my batch duration haven't ended yet, `stream_Value` pushes values to my List for every print that I do.

My question is, why does this happen, and how do I make it so that, independentely of the number of print() methods I use, I get just one JSON line stored in my list per Batch Duration/per execution.

I hope I was not confusing, as I am new to Spark and may have confused some of the vocabulary. Thank you so much.

PS: Even if I print another DStream, the same thing happens. Say I do this, each with same 'architecture' of the Stream above:

```
JavaDStream1.print();
JavaDStream2.print();
```

At the end of JavaDStream2.print(), the list within JavaDstream1 has one extra value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spark Streaming uses the same computation model as Spark. The operations we declare on the data form a Direct Acyclic Graph (DAG) that's evaluated when actions are used to materialize such computations on the data.

In Spark Streaming, output operations, such as `print()` will schedule the materialization of these operations at every batch interval.

The DAG for this Stream would look something like this:

```
[TextStream]->[map]->[print]
```

`print` will schedule the `map` operation on the data received by the `socketTextStream`. When we add more `print` actions, our DAG looks like:

```
            /->[map]->[print]
[TextStream] ->[map]->[print]
            \->[map]->[print]
```

And here the issue should become visible. The `map` operation is executed three times. That's expected behavior and normally not an issue, because `map` is supposed to be a stateless transformation.

The root cause of the problem here is that map contains a mutation operation, as it adds elements to a global collection `stream_Value` defined outside the scope of the function passed to `map`.

This not only causes the duplication issues, but will not work in general, when Spark Streaming runs in its usual cluster mode.

Comment: Thank you so much. Very complete answer